# Camera glitches in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have camera glitches in a first-person game, even if I have high framerate (because there's nothing that big that can cause glitches). Actually it works normally most of the time, but if you rotate your camera fast and frequently, it can cause something like a frame skip, and the camera moves a little bit farther that you expect it to be.

The problem exists no matter VSync is enabled or disabled.

Here's the code of the camera rotation:

```
[SerializeField] private Camera cam;
private const float CAMERA_UPPER_CLAMP = -90f;
private const float CAMERA_LOWER_CLAMP = 54f;
private float sensitivity = 20f;
private float xRotation;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Look();
}

private void Look()
{
    float mouseX = PlayerInput.Instance.GetLookingAxis().x * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = PlayerInput.Instance.GetLookingAxis().y * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, CAMERA_UPPER_CLAMP, CAMERA_LOWER_CLAMP);

    cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

And the code where you get Camera Input:

```
public Vector2 GetLookingAxis()
{
    return playerInputActions.OnFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
```

Here's the build of the game, hope someone with similar experience or someone who sees the problem in the code can help.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pJXV_Uvn1qQUxS49tPv4oiRn0eTEnvPS?usp=sharing